# FTDI recognized but not SIM900a

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, usb, devices

Trying to work with driver of [Sim900a](https://europe1.discourse-cdn.com/arduino/original/4X/d/d/3/dd3d870a4b481fe85893bef9719c4e5de577d56d.jpeg). Using an FTDI232 to connect it to usb port of my laptop which is running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. However, when I `dmesg`, I get FTDI recognized but not the modem.

```
[ 5456.623485] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 5456.777992] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001, bcdDevice= 6.00
[ 5456.778010] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5456.778018] usb 1-4: Product: FT232R USB UART
[ 5456.778025] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: FTDI
[ 5456.778030] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 00000000
[ 5456.795621] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[ 5456.795632] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[ 5456.800110] usbcore: registered new interface driver ftdi_sio
[ 5456.800136] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
[ 5456.800243] ftdi_sio 1-4:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[ 5456.800318] usb 1-4: Detected FT232RL
[ 5456.800789] usb 1-4: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Separate power for Sim900a is given from the other usb port using a simple cable (male-to-male) with a breadboard regulator. Have not inserted the SIM. Sim900a is blinking normally (once every second, as it should be without SIM).

Connections:

```
Sim900a TX (3VT) -> FTDI RX

Sim900a RX (3VR) -> FTDI TX

Sim900a VCC -> FTDI VCC

Sim900a GND -> FTDI GND
```

Tried AT commands with atcom:
`atcom --port /dev/ttyUSB0 AT`
gives
`[ERR]   Timeout, couldn't get response`

I want ttyUSB0-3 to detect it as modem like this:

```
option 2-3:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
usb 2-3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
option 2-3:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
usb 2-3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
option 2-3:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
usb 2-3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
option 2-3:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
usb 2-3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The ftdi chip is just a serial interface to your PC. Bring attached via USB, it identifies itself as such, and automatisms to make it available as serial port can run.

A serial port, unlike USB, has no means of self-identification for devices. You need to know that there's a modem, and not say, an emergency shutdown controller for a chemical plant or an airbag controller attached to a serial port. You don't want to send modem commands to the latter!

So, you either need to explicitly tell your modem manager that yes, there's a modem at that specific port, or need software to very aggressively just take serial pets and assume there is a modem there.

You will also need to make sure that baudrate, stop bits, framing is set appropriately for the device - there's also not a protocol to negotiate these! If nothing reacts visible, wrong baudrate would be the first guess. Usually, you'd attach a logic analyzer to the serial port, and hope for it to respond with a sorry don't understand you in the correct baudrate.

Comment: How do I explicitly tell the system about the modem? Do I modify the option.c file?

Comment: Or should I switch to Beaglebone or RPI instead? That way (I think) I can connect the SIM900a directly through serial port.

Comment: Again, which serial port you use doesn't matter - there's no auto-detection. So, forget about the RPI/BB.

Comment: You need to configure modem manager. That is well-documented.

Comment: This one right? https://snapcraft.io/modem-manager
Thanks, I shall give it a go. So far it is saying 'error: couldn't get bus: Could not connect: Permission denied'. But I will dive deeper.

Comment: Why ever you'd put a system service in a snap! You should be able to install modemmanager directly using apt.

Comment: Ok I removed the snap version and installed the apt version. I tested my Sim900a through Arduino IDE on Windows using an MCU to send AT commands and they work just fine. So my modem works but I still cannot get modem manager to recognize it even under debug mode.